# Oracle Select Query Populate default value as NA in the row

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Let us assume the query is
select con, a, b, c, d, e from the test_table where con in (1,2,3,4,5);

Now for 1,2,4,5, the table has data but for 3 no data is there.

So the output will look like this.

```
con     a      b     c     d     e
1       s1     s2    s3    s4   s5
2       s3     s5    s6    s7   s2
4       s3     s7    s1    s5   s8
5       s4     s8    s4    s7   s8



 but how to get the result as follows

con     a      b     c     d     e
1       s1     s2    s3    s4   s5
2       s3     s5    s6    s7   s2
3       N/A    N/A   N/A   N/A  N/A
4       s3     s7    s1    s5   s8
5       s4     s8    s4    s7   s8
```

Need help. Tried different combinations but was not able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with   helper (con) as (select level from dual connect by level <= 5)
select con, a, b, c, d, e
from   helper left outer join test_table using (con)
;
```

**EDIT**

A more general approach (which can also be adapted for strings instead of numbers in the `IN` list):

```
with helper (con) as (select column_value from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4,5)))
........
```

Comment: This con can be any condition,  it can be any string as well, I just added one example so that my query can be understood.

Comment: @DipakChatterjee - I don't understand your comment. Whatever values you would have in your `IN` list, you can create a "helper table" from those values. Instead of using a `connect by` query, you can `(select column_value from sys.odcivarchar2list('ab1', 'cd2', ....)` (if the list is a list of strings), etc. The key idea is the `helper` view, it doesn't matter **how** you populate it with the same values that would be in the `IN` list.

Comment: Understood, but left outer join will show null I guess, How to show some text there? Like my question. I want in every cell N/A, I was trying to do that.

Comment: Done, used Case function did not know as MYSQL here also CASE function available.

Comment: @DipakChatterjee - Now I understand your comment. Question though: you could use N/A instead of null (empty string) everywhere in the output, or only in the full rows created due to the missing `con` values in `test_table` (but keeping `null` as is when that's what was in the `test_table`). Which one do you need? Either way can be done easily, but the solution is slightly different for the two cases.